# How to get an ASP.NET MVC Navigation Bar to be horizontal instead of vertical?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, navbar

In my MVC5 page, the navigation bar options are not side-by-side, but vertically collapsed:

[image: Collapsed]
[image: Uncollapsed]
Is the setting for this in the index page or in bootstrap.css? Here is a section of my bootstrap.css in case that helps:

```
.navbar-nav {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

    .navbar-nav .nav-link {
        padding-right: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
        position: static;
        float: none;
    }

.navbar-text {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 0.5rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.navbar-collapse {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not from the bootstrap library. The `navbar` which is seen when you create a new project is the default `navbar`. If you want to change it to a left `navbar`, bootstrap has different `navbar` classes which it exposes you to you. For instance you can change the class attribute to

```
class="navbar navbar-left"
```

Or visit [BootStrap Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/)